# Can an asy environment go in a raisebox?

Tags: asymptote

I frequently put a graphic into a raisebox, like:

```
\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics{myfigure}}
```

Is it possible to do this with something like

```
\begin{asy}
size(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(1,1)); 
\end{asy}
```

environment in place of \includegraphics{myfigure}? If you directly substitute you get an error, which I think is because you can't have asy environments as arguments of TeX commands. I don't want to use includegraphics because I want to take advantage of asymptote's 3D PRC graphics.

Comment: Since asymptote is running as an external program, it is at best fragile.  What can you fit it into?  Can you get it into a minipage or a savebox?  (MikTeX user here.  No asymptote.)

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimum example of what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a box bin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\newsavebox{\myasybox}

\begin{document}

Normal
\begin{asy}
size(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(1,1));
\end{asy}
Normal

Raised
\begin{lrbox}{\myasybox}
\begin{asy}
size(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(1,1));
\end{asy}
\end{lrbox}\raisebox{-.5\height}{\usebox{\myasybox}}
Raised

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can't have `asy` environments as arguments of TeX commands. But there are a couple other options:

1. Usually you can add an invisible line or point in the `asy` drawing to get you extra whitespace on the bottom. Unfortunately this concept does not apply very well to interactive `prc` graphics, because the invisible point/line would rotate with the rest of the graphic.
2. You can actually put an `asy` environment inside a `tikz` node. (Ti*k*Z "works some magic" so that `\node` commands behave like environments.) So, something like this (not tested):

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [white] (0,0) (0,1) node [above right] {%
   \begin{asy}
   size(1cm);
   draw((0,0)--(1,1)); 
   \end{asy}
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

Comment: Thanks--the TikZ trick is very cool. I will keep that in mind.